# Easier way to walk through history axis in Git?

Tags: git

Say I discovered a bug during development and I want to do regression tests to see when it was introduced. I would like to be able to rewind Git history without risk of detaching HEAD. Ideally I would also like to avoid using SHA (which is an extra step to find and copy) and use relative pointers where I currently am on the history axis (sort of `move -1` or `move +2`).

I don't see an easy way to do that. Well, except moving back (`git reset --soft HEAD@{1}`). But what about going forward? would I have to get back to last commit and rewind again by different amount of commits? Are there any aliases that one could make to have helper commands and make life easier?

Comment: You want `git bisect`.

Answer (score 3):

You have the option of using `git bisect` (as others told you), or simply of `git checkout master~N`, N being the number of commits back from the current master, this being the number you can always increment or decrement. Don't be afraid of the "detached head" state - despite the scary warning, there is nothing wrong with being in that state, especially if you don't commit. (You can always use `git stash` to move fixes, if any, from that commit to the current master.)

Resetting the branch to `HEAD@{N}` is probably a bad idea because that syntax refers to reflog entries, which don't contain the entire history, but only the historical tips of the current branch.

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly what [`git bisect`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) is for.

Note that, as noted in [Making `git bisect` more useful](http://blogs.perl.org/users/ovid/2014/07/making-git-bisect-more-useful.html), you can avoid marking manually each iterator as "good" or "bad" by running your regression test, and letting `git bisect` mark the commit depending on the exit status of the script:

```
prove t/test/that/fails
git bisect good
prove t/test/that/fails
git bisect bad
```

> No matter how wonderful `git bisect` is, I hate the boring repetition.   However, you can automate this away, too. After you start your bisect and mark your starting and ending commits as good and bad, you can then do this:

```
git bisect run prove t/test/that/fails
```

> And `git bisect` will happily run the test for you and mark commits good or bad as appropriate, using the exit code of the program. You just sit back and wait for it to finish.
>   *Much* nicer.